# .htaccess HTTPS redirects working but HTTPS going to /index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

`HTTP` requests to my site always redirect to `index.php` where as `HTTPS` requests do not request `index.php` at all and work as expected.

For example:

`https://example.com/contact` does not redirect and works as expected.

`http://example.com/contact` redirects to `https://example.com/index.php` and does not load the proper requested page.

My current `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

# Force HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ may help you with your testing.

Comment: If `/contact` is not a file or directory, it will be rewritten to `index.php`, no matter if it is `http` or `https`. Maybe there are additional rules? And if `contact` is a file, it won't be rewritten in either case.

Comment: These are the only rules I have set. And I am certain when hitting https it redirects correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by this part :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

http://example.com/contact becomes http://example.com/index.php because of the rewrite rule just above,
and then your rewrite rule that force https rewrites it in https://example.com/index.php

I don't know what you intend to do with the part I quoted, but try to comment it and test again.